# What are the hardest problems that are in P if and only if P=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard

I used to think that NP complete problems are the "hardest" problems of all problems that would still be in P if P=NP. Now I think otherwise. What I'm asking is if there are any problems that are proved (/believed/maybe) to be harder than NP-Complete if $P\neq NP$, but are certainly in P if $P=NP$.

I was thinking of the sequence

$x_0 = P$

$x_{n+1} = $"All problems that have a checking algorithm in $x_n$"

e.g. $x_1 = NP$

If $P=NP$, then $x_n = P$ for all $n$. But if $P\neq NP$ is then $x_{n+1}$ different from $x_n$ for all $n$? Is this an ever continuing sequence so that there is no "hardest problem that meets the criteria" (because there would always be a harder one), or does this also hold for $x_\infty$ and would that be the hardest problem that meets the criteria? Or are there even harder such problems?

Comment: See [PH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy) and [thes](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5463/6973)e [two](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2032/6973) questions. ​ ​

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, here is a trivial example of a problem.

Inputs: a program P, an input x
Desired output: if P=NP, output "sweet!", else if P halts on x output "halts", else output "doesn't halt"

If P=NP, then this problem is in P.  If P$\ne$NP, then this problem is very hard (it's undecidable).

I realize this might not be what you're looking for; if so, perhaps it illustrates just how tricky it is to specify properties of this sort.

Comment: How would you implement "if p=np" on a TM?

Comment: @adrianN It's the specification, not the implementation. You don't need to implement it.

Comment: @adrianN It's a constant.

Comment: (P = NP) is a constant boolean expression with currently unknown value. We don't know today if it is a trivial problem or an undecidable problem, but it is either one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

You have to say what "harder" means, that is which kind of *reduction* you want to use to order problems.

If you consider poly-time many-one reductions, all problems in P are equally hard.

If you consider log-space many-one reductions, we get a non-trivial set of [P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete) problems.

If you consider ... I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer: Any problem that is NP-hard, that is today believed not to be in NP, but that actually *can* be proved to be in NP (except for the fact that nobody has yet been able to do so).

Obviously if P = NP then any problem that can be proved to be in NP is actually in P.